# AWS ECS & Prisma2 & RDS: Connect local machine to private DB for migration with prisma?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, prisma2

I deployed my Full-Stack project to AWS ECS(Docker). Everything is working so far. My problem is that I don't know how to connect my local machine to the RDS-DB to migrate my DB-Schema.

I want to run the command: `prisma migrate deploy --preview-feature` --> creates Tables and Fields in the DB

My RDS-DP is **private(no public accessibility)** and is in the same VPC as my frontend and backend. The frontend has a public security-group(Load-Balencer) and the backend a private security group and has permissions to the DB(Request is working just get the error: "The table `public.Game` does not exist in the current database" which I can solve with the migration). At the moment only my backend can access the RDS.

I also tried it with a test DB which was public(public accessibility) and I was able to migrate from my local machine.

How do you general migrate Prisma in production and how can I give my local machine permission to RDS with **no public accessibility**?

Answer (score 1):

IF you can run that command from one of the containers you deployed with ECS AND you deployed the ECS tasks on EC2 instances you can `ssh` into the instances and `docker exec` into the container (that has connectivity to the RDS db) from which you can, supposedly, run that command. Note that it is possible that your instances themselves would not be publicly available and reachable from your laptop (in which case you'd need to have some sort of bastion host to do that).

IF you can run that command from one of the containers you deployed with ECS AND you deployed the ECS tasks on Fargate this is a bit more tricky as there are no EC2 instances you can SSH into. In this case I guess you'd need to deploy a temporary environment (on EC2 or ECS/EC2 that would allow to run that command to prepare the DB.

FYI we are releasing a new feature soon that will allow you to `exec` into the container (running on either ECS/EC2 or ECS/Fargate) without having to do those jumps (when possible). But this feature is not (yet) available. More [here](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1050).

Answer (score 1):

If you have it running in ECS, it might be simple to create another Task Definition that uses the same Docker image, but overrides the command parameter to run the migrate command instead of the normal command to start your app. Another similar approach would be to use the CLI to run the `aws ecs run-task` command and execute it that way.